# Jenkins controller-agent connection problem

Tags: jenkins

I moved my Jenkins controller to another server, so I moved all necessary files to new server and restarted the service and its running.

But somehow agents is not connecting to the controller, despite SSH connection is ok.

```
[02/29/24 14:40:02] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[02/29/24 14:40:02] [SSH] java -version returned 17.0.10.
[02/29/24 14:40:02] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[02/29/24 14:40:02] [SSH] Copying latest remoting.jar...
java.io.IOException: Could not copy remoting.jar into '/home/server1' on agent
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copyAgentJar(SSHLauncher.java:717)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$300(SSHLauncher.java:113)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:457)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$1.call(SSHLauncher.java:423)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid len argument
    at com.trilead.ssh2.SFTPv3Client.read(SFTPv3Client.java:1232)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.jenkins.SFTPClient$SFTPInputStream.read(SFTPClient.java:172)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArrayInternal(ByteStreams.java:195)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:242)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.readInputStreamIntoByteArrayAndClose(SSHLauncher.java:775)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copyAgentJar(SSHLauncher.java:686)
    ... 7 more
[02/29/24 14:40:02] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/29/24 14:40:02] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I checked pretty much but couldn't find any solution.